# How to change the date format on display using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `datetime` value in `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` format **e.g. "2017-04-03 05:00:07"**. I don't want to change the value but need to display the value as `"MMM DD, YYYY"` format **e.g. "Apr 03, 2017"**.

Is there anyway to display the value in different format using html?

Comment: did you try using momentjs https://momentjs.com/

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: you have to create directive for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: moment("2017-04-03 05:00:07").format('MMM DD, YYYY')
 would give "Apr 03, 2017"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: This kind of question is solved more than once. Please search before asking.

Comment: Can I use this moment() in html ?

Comment: Provide date format for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve your requirement is by using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
var TodayDate = moment().format('MMM DD, YYYY');
var selectedDate = moment('2017-04-03 05:00:07').format('MMM DD, YYYY');
console.log("today = "+TodayDate);
console.log("selected = "+selectedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

refer the angular filter in the below link.

use this 'MMM' format in default date filter available in the angular js to obtain the month and use the formats in the required order

{{1288323623006 | date:'MMM-dd-yyyy'}} try this

### https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: I want to convert from "2017-04-03 05:00:07" to "2017/04/03" in html.

Answer (score 0):

Create directive as below and use in HTML:

**Directive:**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

var datefrmt = "yyyy-MM-dd";

app.directive('dateFormateModel', function (dateFilter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link:function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {            
            var dateFormat = datefrmt;           
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, dateFormat);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="propertyValue"><input type="text" ng-model="gc.tempApplicationSettingModel.CreatedDate" date-formate-model class="form-control"  /></div>
```